# Find all Users that have red, green and blue shirts

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to select all users that have shirts with colors "red", "green", "blue".

I don't want to select users with more or less or different colors. Only those who exactly possess shirts with these colors.

In my example, user with id 1 and 4 match this criteria.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use the `HAVING` clause to make sure the 3 different colors are there, but no other colors.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT shirt_color) = 3
   and COUNT(case when shirt_color = 'blue' then 1 end) > 0
   and COUNT(case when shirt_color = 'red' then 1 end) > 0
   and COUNT(case when shirt_color = 'green' then 1 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (user_id, shirt_color) are unique the following should work:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id
-- exactly 3 shirts
-- and those shirts are red, green or blue
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN shirt_color IN ('red', 'green', 'blue') THEN 'yay!' END) = 3
```

Comment: Why `THEN 1 END`? Wouldnt it return 1 != 3 which is false?

Please explain

Comment: `COUNT` counts not null values. The count needs to match 3, the value being counted does not matter... 1, 0, -1, 'foo'... they all work.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to counting the colors individually is to use `group_concat()`:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having group_concat(shirt_color order by shirt_color) = 'blue,green,red';
```

Note:  You will need `distinct` if colors can be duplicated for a given user.

Comment: `group_concat` isnt this implying order?

Comment: @Hairi . . . I don't understand your comment.  But without `order by`, `group_concat()` does not guarantee the ordering of the components of the resulting string.